# left align not working in Markdown html output document R

Tags: r, markdown, right-align

I have a shiny application with a `fluidRow` divided into 3 columns. I have text in the first and third column and an image in the second (middle) column. The text in the first and the third column are written in the `Markdown` files with `output: html_document:`.

I need the text in the first column to be aligned to the right side i.e. towards the image in the second column. I tried the below, which did not work.

```
`<p align = right>

 <h5>my heading bla bla</h5>
 <h6>my text bla bla</h6></p>`
```

and

```
 `<right>

 <h5>my heading bla bla</h5>
 <h6>my text bla bla</h6></right>`
```

None of these two ways is changing the alignment. It did not work even when tried to align `left` and it works only to align `center`.

What could be wrong here? any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text using *div* tags:

```
My text aligned to the right:

<div align="right"> 
<h5>my heading bla bla</h5>
<h6>my text bla bla</h6></p>
</div>
```

[image]